# User-alterable attribute-value form in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nunjucks

I have a form, in which the  fields are being loaded with Nunjucks.

```
    {% for item in attr_val %}
      <input name="{{ item.attr }}" type="" value="{{ item.attr }}">
      <input name="{{ item.value }}" type="text" value="{{ item.value }}">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

So these are attribute and value pairs that were being loaded from the database. I want the user to be able to change these (both!) values via the form.
The problem is, that `item.attr` and `item.value` belong together pairwise. If I were to just send the form like this, I would end up with a JSON like this one:

```
{ attr_1: 'attr_1',
  value_1: 'value_1',
  attr_2: 'attr_2',
  value_2: 'value_2',
 //and so on... }
```

But obviously I want to have the following:

```
{ attr_1: 'value_1',
  attr_2: 'value_2'}
```

But of course the user can not change the corresponding html `name` fields, but only the value fields.
Is there any trick to do this straightforward, instead of having to reparse the json before sending it?

Comment: You really want to allow the user to change the first field?

Comment: I don't know the Nunjucks syntax for it, but I would make those `name`s `name1` and `value1`, `name2` and `value2`, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I want to.